# Mwarray.dll for Unity - How can I use it?

Tags: visual-studio, matlab, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with the `MWArray.dll` which is the original dll library from mathworks compiled from Matlab. This dll works under visual studio but not under unity. The goal was to compile under matlab a simple function mycos which calculates a cosinus and uses it under unity with the second dll MWArray mathworks library.

I made a test under Visual Studio and it works well. I have no problem to read the dll and make a call to the mycos.dll class. I made a typical c# project with two references on MWArray and mycos.

But when I try under unity, by putting the two dll under a plugins folder and configure unity 2018 on .NET 4.0 because the dll are compiled with the .NET framework 4.0.

Unity can read the dll but when running I get an error:

```
NotImplementedException: The requested feature is not implemented. 
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent (Boolean ifImpersonating) 
(at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Security.Principal/WindowsIdentity.cs:166)
```

If I want to use matlab for a research project which was coded in matlab with advanced high level math functions which going to be difficult to recode under unity with c#. So the easy way is to use compiled package from matlab compiler. So is there someone who did this already?

Comment: Related: https://forum.unity.com/threads/use-dll-for-unity3d.132960/ I can't tell from your description what parts are .Net and what parts expect pure C-linkage, so there might be something you need to sort out there. But it also looks like the version of Unity matters.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: That error refers to Mono. Pretty sure MWArray.dll is built with the .Net framweork, not Mono, so that's not going to work.. Could try building a plain C dll of your Matlab function and call that?

Answer (score 0):

The solution consists in NOT using MWArray.dll in Unity project because of incompatibility with Mono. Create a Visual Studio project (when creating new select the type "console applicatiion"), it MUST be separated from unity project directory, and use it as an application server; in fact in that app you can use MWArray.dll, remember that you have to configure your project configuration to x64!!! In the Unity project create a client app to communicate with the other server project.